# how to combine multiple columns and multiple rows based on group by of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine multiple columns and rows into single column based on group by field of ID column. The input is

```
|Id |   Sample_id | Sample_name |   Sample_number|
|:--|:------------|:-----------:|---------------:|             
|1  |  123        | Abcdef|ghij |  1234567       |
|1  |   345       | Vbnhj|tt|t  |   45678        |
|1  |   456       | Ffff|yyy|yy |   789000       |
```

Expected output : columns,rows belonging to same Id should be combined and form a list like below.

```
Id  Sample_details              
    123,Abcdef|ghij,1234567
 1  345,Vbnhj|tt|t, 45678       
    456 ,Ffff|yyy|yy,789000

 2   536 ,Ftff|uyy|iy,79000
     453, hnhj|tdd|rr, 67678
```

I tried below which is not working

```
df.groupby('Id')['Sample_id']['Sample_name']['Sample_number'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Your outcome is not clear. Do you want to join by ',' for each row and join rows by '\n' to keep only one Id? So what do you mean by *combined and form a list like*?

Comment: yes you are correct , i want to join each column by , and each row by \n , for the grouped id.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Sample_details'] = df.filter(like='Sample_').astype(str).apply(','.join, axis=1)

out = df.groupby('Id')['Sample_details'].apply('\n'.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Id                                     Sample_details
0   1  123,Abcdef|ghij,1234567\n345,Vbnhj|tt|t,45678\...
```

*Note: Pandas does not interpret escape sequence.*

Comment: sorry, im not expecting this. all the list should be in single column row, i dont want 3 different rows in sample details. i'm updating the format in my question how my output should be represented. Thanks

Comment: I have updated question with the expected output format

Comment: @behappy. I updated my answer too if you want to check.